# Buffer Overflow memory address calculation on 64bit

Tags: exploit, buffer-overflow, shellcode

I have a assignment where i must exploit a buffer overflow vulnerability on a remote machine. I have only execute permission on the program, so i cant use gdb. I managed to take control of the rip and i can successfully overflow and write my own address. My shellcode is ready (it has executable stack and ASLR disabled) but i cant find the right address to return. It is a 64bit machine so nop padding is not an option. The main goal is to access a log file which the executable updates every time it runs. (it's a university assignment do not worry about illegal actions)

What can i do? Is there a way to calculate the memory address of the buffer, or another way? Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Do you really need the buffer's address ? Can't you inject your data in the executable when he ask for some inputs ?

Comment: This is what I do, but i need to return to this data so my shellcode executes. I am not sure i understood your question. I inject my shellcode, pad with garbage and then overwrite the return address. Are you suggesting something different?

Comment: The return address is not usually address of the shell code directly. It is usually address of some jump (far or relative, depends what is better in actual case) instruction in main program or one of libraries (usually system libraries) loaded. You have to find such instruction (only with ASLR off it will be always on the same address in memory) then you force CPU to return to this instruction (by filling the stack with appropriate data) then this instruction is supposed to run your code stored using stack overflow method.

Comment: To achieve this you usually need the software you are trying to hack and same kernel + library versions installed on your computer. Also, you need to have some good debugger. Doing this blindly will cause you headache.

Comment: I have the source code and i have compiled it with the right flags so it matches the real. Where can i find the system libraries? Also, i have an idea. What will happen if i store my shellcode in environment variables, find it's address and return to it?

Comment: What kind of OS are you using?

Comment: cat /proc/version
Linux version 3.16.0-4-amd64 (debian-kernel@lists.debian.org) (gcc version 4.8.4 (Debian 4.8.4-1) ) #1 SMP Debian 3.16.43-2 (2017-04-30)

Comment: Ok, this topic is hard to explain here. Take a look on some video, this one looks good: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eYrfWpkvMxA

Comment: there is a way to attach `ptrace` without having read permission: [How can I analyse an executable with no read permission?](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/98/how-can-i-analyse-an-executable-with-no-read-permission)

Comment: What stops you from doing a nop sled ?

Comment: @PedroJavierFernández I don't know approximately what the address will be so i return close to it. Now i am looking for a way to find the address of the last instruction (ret) so i can calculate the buffer address

Comment: Then Just create a very Big nop sled and by performing tests on your computer with the debbugger, discover  the possible address where the nops may be

Comment: That's what i am saying! i cant load the executable on gdb because of the permissions. If i could i would calculate the outside gdb buffer address and i wouldn't be here asking. Please read the previous comments before trying to answer.

Comment: If you can't predict the address exactly then try to reach the shellcode blindly;  you can simulate the race condition of the target into a VM (same OS, conf and hardware/architecture emulation I.e. RAM) and also take ram dumps at the same time you statically reverse the binary so you can see how the target structure is. You can manually guess the base address and try random offsets into your exploit until you find one that's more accurate than the others. For an universal exploit I would suggest a NOP|Shellcode|NOP|JMP back attempt.

Comment: By the way, your message isn't clear about the binary. Do you have a copy of it or is it running on a server?. If it's the last, I find some weird points in your question, if you don't have access to a debugger how do you know you control rip? If you have access, then ATetereb answer or mine should be useful.

Comment: Oh and as @Fis said, you can try to do it blindly as I suggested (at the moment It's the only way I can imagine to do this since you haven't provided more information) it's very difficult, but not impossible.

Answer (score 3):

If you fimilar with gdb and can control rip, then you are one step away from the solution.

Let's make a small example

```
void main() {
  char* buff = "asdf";
}
```

compile it

```
$ gcc test.c
```

and then use debugger

```
$ gdb a.out
 (gdb) set disassembly-flavor intel
(gdb) disassemble main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
 0x00000000004004d6 <+0>:   push   rbp
 0x00000000004004d7 <+1>:   mov    rbp,rsp
 0x00000000004004da <+4>:   mov    QWORD PTR [rbp-0x8],0x400574
 0x00000000004004e2 <+12>:  nop
 0x00000000004004e3 <+13>:  pop    rbp
 0x00000000004004e4 <+14>:  ret    
End of assembler dump.
```

So our variable buff is at rbp-0x8 on the stack. If ASLR disabled - the address is always the same. You can get it with:

```
(gdb) break *0x00000000004004e2
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4004e2
(gdb) r
Starting program: ./a.out 
Breakpoint 1, 0x00000000004004e2 in main ()
(gdb) p $rbp-0x8
$1 = (void *) 0x7fffffffdbd8
```

Comment: I am not sure i understand you. But in my  case the program is more complicated. There is a function in main which returns another functions exit code and inside the last is strcpy  where i overflow the buffer. So i dont know how to calculate the buffer address like you did.

Comment: Then you need to run (gdb) disassemble <name of the function where strcpy is>. If you post its output here we can look into it.